# Alternative and conjuction in LLVM

Tags: llvm

Is it possible to evaluate some logic expression - conjuction and alternative without using `br` ?   I know that it is possible to do it using `phi` and `br` but I am searching for other way.

Comment: Why? If the outcome of an expression are changing code flow then `br` or `phi` are the way to go.

Comment: There's the [`select` instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#select-instruction)